# Strange behaviour GoLang limits storing of string into a variable to 64 bytes length

Tags: go, couchbase, gocb

I have been trying to store a large string into a string variable in GoLang , but for some unknown reason GoLang is limiting the string to 64 Bytes in length

The main purpose of this string concatenation is to generate a couchbase's N1QL query at runtime based on user input

```
userInput := []string{"apple", "boy", "cat", "dog"} 
var buffer string 
buffer = "SELECT * FROM DB WHERE DB.ITEM_NAME="+userInput[0]+
         "OR DB.ITEM_NAME="+userInput[1]
```

In such a case if I debug on variable buffer, for example I can see it contains only until "SELECT * FROM DB WHERE DB.ITEM_NAME="+userInput[0]+OR" depending upon user input size it varies and it caps the string to 64th character

Comment: Show working code that demonstrates the issue.  The posted code does not compile, but works as expected when the errors are corrected.

Comment: Sure added the working code :)

Comment: Perhaps the problem is your debugging. If you just print out or log the buffer, you will see the full string.

Comment: @SudeshGutta See https://play.golang.org/p/bnsGmejlyu. What about that is not working as expected?

Comment: @CeriseLimón: For example, `DB.ITEM_NAME=appleOR` is almost certainly wrong.

Comment: @CeriseLimón: Since the size of a Go string is represented by an `int` --  Gigabytes for 32-bit systems, Exabytes for 64-bit systems -- the notion of a 64 byte limit is clearly absurd.

Comment: Yes, it's absurd. The goal of my comments is to show the OP that the string operations work as expected and that the problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: It's the debugger that was truncating the characters... thank you all for your support :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behaviour is as expected. The behaviour is not strange.

Your code creates obviously wrong Couchbase N1QL:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    userInput := []string{"apple", "boy", "cat", "dog"}
    var buffer string
    buffer = "SELECT * FROM DB WHERE DB.ITEM_NAME=" + userInput[0] +
        "OR DB.ITEM_NAME=" + userInput[1]
    fmt.Println(buffer)
}
```

Output:

```
SELECT * FROM DB WHERE DB.ITEM_NAME=appleOR DB.ITEM_NAME=boy
```

Here is a plausible solution:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    userInput := []string{"apple", "boy", "cat", "dog"}
    query := fmt.Sprintf(
        `SELECT * FROM DB WHERE DB.ITEM_NAME=%q OR DB.ITEM_NAME=%q;`,
        userInput[0], userInput[1],
    )
    fmt.Println(query)
}
```

Output:

```
SELECT * FROM DB WHERE DB.ITEM_NAME="apple" OR DB.ITEM_NAME="boy";
```

Note: Beware of SQL injection.

References:

[The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)

[Couchbase: Query Language Tutorial](http://query.pub.couchbase.com/tutorial/#1)

[Couchbase: Querying with N1QL](https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/sdk/n1ql-query.html)